# Call different String from Res to .java

Tags: android, string

First, I'm new with android. I've trying to make a survey on android. My problem is that i want that the next question and possible answers appear when radiobutton is selected, and the same thing for all the question i have. I make it function but accidentally i erased the project. Here is the code i developed

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView texto1;
    TextView texto2;
    RadioGroup Selecopc;
    int i=1;
    private TextView num;
    private TextView pregu;
    private TextView rep1;
    private TextView rep2;
    private TextView rep3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.area_de_preguntas);

        num = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Numero);
        pregu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Pregunta);
        rep1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Respuesta1);
        rep2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Respuesta2);
        rep3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Respuesta3);

        Selecopc = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.opcion);

        Selecopc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){   

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            i++;    
            String n = String.valueOf(i);
            num.setText(n);
            String pregseg ="R.string."+"preg"+i;
            pregu.setText(pregseg);         
        }

        });


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="numero">1</string>
    <string name="preg1">Cua...</string>
    <string name="preg2">Cu..</string>
    <string name="preg3">...</string>
    <string name="preg4">...</string>
    <string name="preg5">...</string>
    <string name="preg6">...</string>
```

Comment: It **doesn't work like this**... It works like `pregu.setText(R.getString(R.string.preg2));` You see, `R.string.preg2` **is not a string, it's an integer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String id resource names is just a static field. I suppose you can do it using reflection but it's not the better choice in your case. The better way is to predefine array of identifiers and use them. Sample:

```
private int[] pregs = new int[]{
        R.string.preg1,
        R.string.preg2,
        R.string.preg3
};
```

And use it later like this:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
{
    i++;
    String n = String.valueOf(i);
    num.setText(n);
    pregu.setText(pregs[i]);
}
```